# Second Borel-Cantelli with correlations

Tags: pr.probability

Theorem 2.3.8 of Durrett's *Probability Theory and Examples* gives the following strengthening of the 2nd Borel-Cantelli Lemma:
If $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ are pairwise independent events and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\infty$, then, as $n\to\infty$
$$
\frac{\sum_{m=1}^n \boldsymbol{1}_{A_m}}{
\sum_{m=1}^n P(A_m)
}
\to 1
$$
almost surely.

What is known about the case where pairwise independence is relaxed to some quantitative assumption on the pairwise covariances (i.e., the quantities $P(A_i\cap A_j)-P(A_i)(A_j)$)?

Comment: I remember the BC book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-81-322-0677-4 by  Tapas Kumar Chandra had a survey of many recent results. eg. see Theorem 3.2.2 that contains that difference you wrote.

Comment: That's *extremely* useful, thank you!

Comment: The Kochen-Stone theorem may be relevant. See wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Kochen%E2%80%93Stone